# HTML5 href tel properties related issue

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p><a href="tel:+47333#78901">Call</a></p>
```

When there is a # key in the middle of the number and when I click on 'call' the remaining numbers gets terminate after '#' , when phone dialer opens. This is happening in android phone. while in ios it works fine.

Comment: This seems like an android bug, are you on the latest version? Also, what web browsers are you using? Please also make your title clearer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer